# How to implement image sticker (ribbon) with css3

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to implement following image, one of the old method I can use is  save sticker with text on it as PNG then I place  the image on top of the box with CSS.
[image]

I am not professional front-end developer but I think I can implement it with CSS3 .my question is **How can I implement image sticker with CSS3?**

Comment: It's called "ribbon". just google `codepen corner ribbon`, no need to ask here anything since google is great for finding things. `-1` for not googling.

Comment: you can use [Codepen](http://codepen.io) to find such things. type "corner ribbon" in the search box

Comment: @vsync yes I know, I told you I didn't know "Ribbon", I search for siticker image of sticky image and didn't find what did I want, so ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a reference from [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/corner-ribbon/) on how to create a corner ribbon using pseudo code.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 280px;
  height: 370px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
}

.ribbon-wrapper-green {
  width: 85px;
  height: 88px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green {
  font: bold 15px Sans-Serif;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px 0;
  left: -5px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #BFDC7A;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A), to(#8EBF45)); 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  color: #6a6340;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.ribbon-green:before, .ribbon-green:after {
  content: "";
  border-top:   3px solid #6e8900;   
  border-left:  3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green:before {
  left: 0;
}
.ribbon-green:after {
  right: 0;
}​
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
       <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green"><div class="ribbon-green">News</div></div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 1):

means giving the ribbon in the picture?
look here might be able to provide a solution that you want

http://www.cssportal.com/css-ribbon-generator/

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="https://github.com/you"><img style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; border: 0;" src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/82b228a3648bf44fc1163ef44c62fcc60081495e/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f6769746875622f726962626f6e732f666f726b6d655f6c6566745f7265645f6161303030302e706e67" alt="Fork me on GitHub" data-canonical-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_left_red_aa0000.png"></a>
```

[**Demo2**](https://github.com/simonwhitaker/github-fork-ribbon-css)

[**Demo**](https://github.com/blog/273-github-ribbons)